# Наложение колонок друг на друга Bootstrap

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap, bootstrap4, grid

Есть две колонки

```
<div class="row m-0 d-flex align-items-center mb-5">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12" style="padding:0">
        <div class="led-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12" style="padding:0">
        <div class="jumbotron m-0">
            <h2 class="h1-responsive pb-3">Lorem</h2>
            <p class="lead">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris felis sapien, egestas vel elit vel, ullamcorper egestas ante. Nulla aliquet urna ut
                laoreet venenatis. Vestibulum vehicula varius leo et accumsan. Fusce at risus rhoncus, scelerisque tellus sollicitudin, mollis justo. Praesent molestie
                ante ligula, vel placerat mi pretium vel.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Было]

Как сделать чтобы правая колонка накладывалась на левую по средствам Bootstrap, чтобы выглядело это примерно так:[image: Стало]

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```css
.right {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  
  margin-left: -8.333333%;
}

.left {
  margin-right: -8.333333%;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) { 
  .left,
  .right {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex-sm-nowrap align-items-center">

    <div class="col-sm-7 left">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1540946646613-e038c58270fb?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=695dfc59fc56bab4bb27abafe804594d&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-7 right">
      <div class="text bg-white p-4">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus dolorum quis quia corporis, architecto, suscipit tenetur. Aliquam recusandae dignissimos dolore blanditiis soluta animi unde, cupiditate fugit officia, ab et tempore. Tenetur cumque iste, sed consequuntur, quia vel. Veniam hic sapiente nemo, fugit, tempore pariatur, aut neque esse cumque minima deserunt.
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Могу подсказать только через `position:absolute` для блока внутри и `@media` запросы.

```css
 .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
    float: left;
 }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
 }
 .jumbotron {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 120%;
    background-color: #fff;
 }
 
@media(min-width:992px){
    .jumbotron {
      position:relative;
      width:100%;
    }
}
@media(min-width:1200px){
    .jumbotron {
      
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row m-0 d-flex align-items-center mb-5">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12" style="padding:0">
        <div class="led-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12" style="padding:0">
        <div class="jumbotron m-0">
            <h2 class="h1-responsive pb-3">Lorem</h2>
            <p class="lead">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris felis sapien, egestas vel elit vel, ullamcorper egestas ante. Nulla aliquet urna ut laoreet venenatis.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше внутренний контейнер jumbotron выравнивать либо отрицательным margin, либо через position absolute, как сказали выше. Еще вариант для общего контейнера через псевдо ::before задать background-image с шириной 66%, ну или сколько хотите

Answer (score 0):

Вроде то что вы хотели [пример на codepen](https://codepen.io/Ercogx/pen/YRzpbg)

```
<div class="row m-0 d-flex align-items-center mb-5">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12" style="padding:0">
    <div class="led-1">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600" alt="">
        </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 wrap_1" style="padding:0">
    <div class="jumbotron m-0">
        <h2 class="h1-responsive pb-3">Lorem</h2>
        <p class="lead">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris felis sapien, egestas vel elit vel, ullamcorper egestas ante. Nulla aliquet urna ut
            laoreet venenatis. Vestibulum vehicula varius leo et accumsan. Fusce at risus rhoncus, scelerisque tellus sollicitudin, mollis justo. Praesent molestie
            ante ligula, vel placerat mi pretium vel.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.led-1 img{
    width: 100%;
}
.wrap_1{
    position: relative;
}
@media(min-width:1200px){
    .jumbotron{
        position: absolute;
        left: -70px;
        /*Для центрирования по вертикали*/
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -193px!important;
    }
}
```